# C function passes a pointer and a length, and a Python callback needs to make an array and assign it

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm wrapping a C library that uses callbacks as external memory allocators.  Basically, instead of doing malloc and free itself, it exposes several callbacks for making buffers of specified sizes.  Hooking those up with ctypes is fairly easy, and all that seems to be working.  However, I can't seem to connect the array to the pointer that's passed in.

The C interface looks something like this:

```
extern int (*alloc_int_buffer_callback)(some_struct* buffer, uint32_t length);
```

I've got the struct defined through ctypes, and it seems to match up perfectly.

The ctypes callbacks look something like this:

```
_int_functype = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(some_struct), c_uint)
```

The problem I'm having is that trying to get the POINTER(some_struct) instance to point at an array of type (c_int * length) doesn't seem to work.  Here's the callback I've got right now:

```
def _alloc_struct_buffer(ptr, length):
    arr_type = SomeStruct * length
    arr = arr_type()

    ptr.contents = cast(addressof(arr), POINTER(SomeStruct))

    return 1
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error along the lines of "Expected SomeStruct instead of LP_SomeStruct".  What am I missing?

Comment: Your C prototype has return type `int*`, while your ctypes prototype has return type `int`.  Which one is right?

Comment: Whoops, I mistyped that.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a pointer in a parameter, you need to pass in a pointer to a pointer:

```
extern int alloc_int_buffer_callback(some_struct **buffer, uint32_t length);
```

If you simply pass in a pointer, changing the pointer inside the function does nothing, since you passed the pointer by value.

Inside your Python callback, you can use

```
ptr.contents = cast(arr, POINTER(SomeStruct))
```

after changing the prototype.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm now getting segfaults when the C code tries to access the memory.

Comment: @Lee: You need to store a reference to `arr` in some more persistent Python data structure.  If you only create it locally in the callback, it will be garbage collected immediately.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Some days I wonder how I manage to feed myself.  Thanks.